# GetRectFromCharacterIndex returning infinity values instead of actual rect values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout, adorner

I'm trying to get a rect representing the location of some text inside of a textBox in WPF.

The problem I am having is that the values being return for the rect are returning as "Infinity".

rect.X is really all I care about.

If I call this method on a textChanged event, for example, it works.

Calling this method inside of TextBox.Loaded event is returning the above.  I'm looking for any insight into what I may be missing.

It's my understanding that the layout hasn't calculated yet, but even attached to the LayoutUpdated() event of the TextBox doesn't work.

Some code if it will show anything:

```
foreach (var word in rslt)
{
  //find the index of the start of the invalid word
  int idx1 = tbx.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(word.ToLower());
  //find the index of the end of the invalid word
  int idx2 = idx1 + (word.Length);

  if (idx1 == -1)
    continue;

  //get a rect defining the location in coordinates of the invalid word.
  var rec1 = tbx.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(idx1);
  var rec2 = tbx.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(idx2);

  //if the word is not visible or not fully visible, do not show the red line.
  if (tbx.ActualWidth > 0)
  {
    if (rec1.X < 0 || rec2.X > tbx.ActualWidth)
      continue;
  }

  if (rec1.Y < 0)
    continue;

  //actually draw the line under the word
  SquigglyAdorner ado = new SquigglyAdorner(tbx, word, rec1.X, rec2.X, rec2.Bottom);
  adornerLayer.Add(ado);
}
```